# PHP - Displaying data in a Table Row

Tags: php

I am developing a forum, I have a text area where users input their comment, and I am displaying it in a table row. But I do find that the data is not fully displayed , I mean while creating a post if I enter 500 characters, the table row displays only limited characters restricted to the width of the row. Is there any way to display the data entirely in row?

```
 Here is the code that displays the message;refer to line - echo "<td>" .    
//$row['usermessage'] . "</td>";


echo "<table class='zebra'>
<thead>
<tr>`enter code here`
<th> Original Message by " . $row['username'] . " posted at " .     
$row['cqatime'] . " IST</th>
</tr>
</thead>";              
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['usermessage'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";       
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Post the exact error u gotten

Comment: There is no error, I mean that the data is not displayed fully in a table row

Comment: can you post your class=zebra CSS so that we can know whats happening..

Answer (score 1):

Use h1-4 and p. 
Ex:

```
<h1>From: <?php echo $row['username'] ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row['usermessage']?></p>
```

P is for paragraphs of text. Perfect if its a message like that. No need for a table. Tables are to display tabular data. Like a products list or something like that.

Also, and this is personal, I never output html like you did. I prefer the way I posted.

edit: since you are getting errors I'll do it your way.

```
echo '<h1>From: ' .  $row['username'] . '</h1>';
echo '<p>' . $row['usermessage'] . '</p>';
```

Comment: Can you please edit the code that I have shown..? While I try to add Hi and P tags it shows an error..

Comment: There you go @fishspy

Comment: to display it in a table, this code has to be inside a TR and it still can't display all the data ; echo '<h1>From: ' .  $row['username'] . '</h1>';
echo '<p>' . $row['usermessage'] . '</p>';

Comment: echo "<table class='zebra'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
  <th> Original Message by " . $row['username'] . " posted at " . $row['cqatime'] . " IST</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>";
  
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
            echo '<p>' . $row['usermessage'] . '</p>';
   echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
  echo "</tbody>";
  
    
  
 echo "</table>";

Answer (score 1):

TD should show the full message unless the width of the TD is controlled by CSS, e.g. overflow:hidden?

EDIT:

Try:

```
echo "<td style=\"overflow: visible\">" . $row['usermessage'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: I don't see any overflow: hidden in css file .. donno why TD is not displaying

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript/jQuery plugin to handle the table with class="zebra". If so, it must be controlling the display.

Comment: I tried this, still no change - echo "<td style=\"overflow: visible\">" . $row['usermessage'] . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<table class='zebra'>
<tr>`enter code here`
<th> Original Message by ".$row['username']." posted at ".$row['cqatime']." IST</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>".$row['usermessage']."</td>
</tr>
</table>"; ?>
```

Comment: how are you fetching the records?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class='zebra' in your table. That class is controlling the behavior of your table data display.

```
Change the CSS in that class and remove overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I don't see any  overflow: hidden in css file;

Comment: @fishspy 1st check if the $row['usermessage'] contains the full data that you want to display . try printing it separately and put die just after that print to check whats being printed.